# npm cannot install pm2 or nodemon in Windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, pm2, forever, nodemon

I try to install a nodemon for the auto-restart nodejs server when my file has been changed. But I got two warnings so, I try to install other npm packages like forever or pm2, but I still get the same warning.
Here is my warning capture:

[image: warning from npm install]

Comment: you sure it failed? i see 2 warnings, no errors.

Comment: Yes, because after installed I try to run command **pm2 -v** but it show 'pm2' is not recognized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
npm cache clear -f
```

and,

```
npm install pm2 -g --unsafe-perm
```

Answer (score 3):

Windows 10 has execution policy built in that restrict any script execution by default. So, you have to set the policy first.

In Powershell (Admin rights), first look at the ExecutionPolicy with command

> Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

'Undefined' policy means scripts like pm2 will be restricted. To enable it, run command

> Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser

Then, try run pm2.

Comment: This is a solution too if your node app works from the command lone, but not through Task Scheduler. Days of struggle before I ran into this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is an old question but since this is the first result on google and the above solutions did not work for me, I will share my solution.

In my case it was a version issue with npm:
I try to install pm2 with node version 17.8.0 and npm version 8.3.1 but I can not made it.

Based on that issue on github: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4234,
downgrade node version to 16.13.2 and npm version 8.1.2 fix the problem.

using nvm:

```
nvm install 16.13.2
nvm use 16.13.2
npm install -g pm2
```